# How to get a particular word or a string from a sentence for User Reply in Bot Framework Emulator?

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

I am working on a Bot Framework and I am stuck on a problem here.

**Scenario:**

When the user responds like "My Name is ABC", The Bot should reply with Echo saying only his name. That means it should only show ABC.

**Expected:**

**Bot**: What is your name?

**User**: My name is ABC

**Bot**: Hello ABC!

I tried with an if statement checking if the statement contains those words, but no result:

```
    private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> NameStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        stepContext.Values["intro"] = ((FoundChoice)stepContext.Result);

        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("What is your name?") }, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the If statement and how are you retrieving the user input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing a bot, and you think you're going to get back more complicated answers from your users then just one word replies, you're going to need a language understanding service like LUIS. Otherwise, you're going to need a heck of a lot of 'possible' cases in a switch-case.

The purpose of a service like LUIS is to look for things just like what you're describing: When a bot prompts for an answer, but a user replies with something that is *slightly* more complicated or different (Hi, my name is XYZ. or I'm XYZ. or I'm called XYZ. etc).

LUIS is set up to detect an 'intent' (general purpose or category) of an 'utterance' (statement from user). All of the name replies I listed above would be categorized as utterances in a possible 'introduction' intent. You would build a list of utterances in an intent, and then train the service to recognize them. The XYZ portions of the utterances would 'entities', the portion of the utterance that would change with every new user.

I would look over the official LUIS.ai documentation found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/what-is-luis), because based on your question, this is what you're looking for.